# <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> is inserted when modify xml with java

Tags: java, html, xml

I want to modify a html(XML) to add one node. But after that, one element is added as well. And that line will make the file corrupted. So weird. Can any one have a look?

Here is the code.

```
private void linkPrepare(String buildNum) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DocumentBuilderFactory domfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dombuilder;
    try {
        dombuilder = domfac.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(
                "File/test");
        Document doc = dombuilder.parse(is);

        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("div");
        Node firstNode = nodes.item(0);
        Element newNode = doc.createElement("ul");

        firstNode.appendChild(newNode);

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
                .newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(
                "File/test"));
        transformer.transform(source, result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And here is the html file,

```
<html>
<head>
<title>OTA</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<ul></ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The <META> tag is a valid HTML tag (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp). How does it make your HTML file corrupted? Do you use any validators ?

Comment: Sure, it's valid for html. But i want to modify it as XML format for other use. In that case, it's not a valid XML format. @ jeroen_de_schutter

Comment: And what if the document has a valid meta element to begin with? I mean, can you add one to the html before performing this operation? Does that work?

Comment: No, I tried to add a end tag </META> to make it as a valid xml. But in next executation, one same element will be added too..